# Rails 4 testing controller spec ,devise helper sign_in doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec3

I have Rails 4.2.6 and rspec 3.3.0 , devise version 3.5.8 and i have trouble to test my controller specs always getting error saying ***("expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 401")*** 
Later when i try different spec I am always getting failure message ***("Your account is not enabled yet !")***, any ideas ?, any help much appreciated ..

my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MyController, :type => :controller
  let(:user)          { create(:user) }
  let(:campaign)      { create(:campaign, user: user) }
  let!(:placement) { create(:placement, user: user, campaign: campaign, end_date: Date.today) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in user
  end
  context "when we have no data" do
    before do
      get :graph_data, format: :json
      @json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    it "should be a success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

I have following spec_helper:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end
```

factory defined:

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :unconfirmed_user, class: User do
  sequence(:email)  { |n| "john#{n}@email.com" }
  sequence(:name)  { |n| "John Nice #{n}" }
  password 'password'
  password_confirmation 'password'

  factory :user do
      confirmed_at Time.now.utc

      factory :admin do
        organisation { create(:organisation, :some_organisation) }
      end
   end
end
```

controller:

```
MyController < ApplicationController
   def graph_data
     items =  current_user.items           //outputs [1,2,3,45,5]
     render json: items, status: :ok 
   end
 end
```

routes:

```
GET /mycontroller/graph_data(.:format)
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your user is actually being created? I would imagine you are having trouble with the password_confirmation field

Comment: yes i have checked it and user indeed was created

Comment: do you have :confirmable enabled with your devise setup ?

Answer (score 0):

i found what was the issue,on User model had a method 'active_for_authentication?'

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && (group.include?('company-group) || is_admin? )
end
```

Method 'active_for_authentication?' is a Devise public method
 and when it is defined in your model like (User), you change behaviour of it, and in my case it was overwritten with different behaviour,
 checking for belonging user to the 'company-group' or not ..
That's why i had failure message ("Your account is not enabled yet !")